# Error message in Shiny from sourced R script

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to show happenings/errors/warnings from R script which is sourced inside server part of Shiny in Shiny panel?

Following is the sample code which works fine, but I need to see in Shiny if R throws an error while executing sourced `GUI_trials2.R` and if possible, a window to stream the happenings, like which line of `GUI_trials2.R` is running currently.
Sample code -

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Required Calcs", tabName = "Requirements")
)
)

uibody <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(
tabItem(tabName = "Requirements", h2("Required Calcs")
    ,dateInput("ME_DATE_output",label=h2("Execution Date"), value="2020-05-29")
    ,hr()
    ,actionButton("calculate", "Calculate this" ))
))

ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Results"), sidebar, uibody)

server = function(input, output) { 
ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({input$ME_DATE_output})

Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"

observeEvent(input$calculate, {
ME_DATE <- ME_DATE_GUI()
source(paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials2.r"), local = TRUE)
}) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

GUI_trials looks like -

```
# Use ME_DATE from Shiny
ME_DATE <- as.Date(ME_DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")

year_N_ME_DATE <- format(ME_DATE,"%Y")
month_N_ME_DATE <- format(ME_DATE,"%m")
month_T_ME_DATE <- months(ME_DATE)

# Location for Outputs
Output_DIR <- "K:/Outputs/"
Output_loc <- paste(Output_DIR,month_N_ME_DATE,". ",month_T_ME_DATE, " ",year_N_ME_DATE,"/",sep="")

success <- "Success"
write.csv(success, paste0(Output_loc,"Success.csv"))
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Probably, but it depends entirely on the app and how you are sourcing it. Please consider making a *minimal working reproducible example*, you can follow suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that and many thanks as always! I have edited the question now. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `withCallingHandlers()`

You can wrap your call to `source()` as follows and use arbitrary code to handle warnings and messages that arise when the code is run. To handle errors you will need to wrap this again in `tryCatch()` so your app doesn't crash. For example, you could choose to simply send notifications as follows:

```
tryCatch(
  withCallingHandlers(
    source(paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials2.r"), local = TRUE),
    message = function(m) showNotification(m$message, type = "message"),
    warning = function(w) showNotification(w$message, type = "warning")
  ),
  error = function(e) showNotification(e$message, type = "error")
)
```

You can test this by using something like the following code in your `GUI_trials2.R` script:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  warning("This is warning ", i)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  message("This is message", i)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}

stop("This is a fake error!")
```

### Streaming Output in New Window

The easiest way to do this is to pepper your `GUI_trials2.R` script with informative calls to `message()` and then use `withCallingHandlers()` to output these as above. If you want to be more sophisticated and show these messages in a new window, you could do this by updating a `modalDialog()`, though this would require the `shinyjs` package. Here is a basic example:

```
server = function(input, output) { 
  ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({input$ME_DATE_output})
  
  # Show a modal that will be updated as your script is run
  observeEvent(input$calculate, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      title = "Running my R script",
      div("You can put an initial message here", br(), id = "modal_status")
    ))
    
    Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"
    ME_DATE <- ME_DATE_GUI()
    
    # Run the script and use `withCallingHandlers()` to update the modal.
    # add = TRUE means each message will be added to all the previous ones
    # instead of replacing them.
    tryCatch(
      withCallingHandlers(
        source(paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials2.r"), local = TRUE),
        message = function(m) {
          shinyjs::html("modal_status", paste(m$message, br()), add = TRUE)
        },
        warning = function(w) {
          shinyjs::html("modal_status", paste(w$message, br()), add = TRUE)
        }
      ),
      error = function(e) {
        shinyjs::html("modal_status", paste(e$message, br()), add = TRUE)
      }
    )
  }) 
}
```

### Display Code From `source()`

The `echo = TRUE` argument to `source()` will mean that each expression in the file gets printed in the console. Unfortunately, applying handlers to text as it appears in the console isn't possible in R unless it's a `message`/`warning`/`error`, so `echo = TRUE` won't be of any use here. However, you could define a custom function, similar to `source()` which **will** allow you to handle the code as *text* before it gets evaluated. Here is an example:

```
# Default handler just prints the code to console, similar
# to `source(echo = TRUE)`
source2 <- function(file, handler = cli::cat_line, local = FALSE) {
  
  # Copy `source()` method of handling the `local` argument
  envir <- if (isTRUE(local)) 
    parent.frame()
  else if (isFALSE(local)) 
    .GlobalEnv
  else if (is.environment(local)) 
    local
  else stop("'local' must be TRUE, FALSE or an environment")
  
  # Read each 'expression' in the source file
  exprs <- parse(n = -1, file = file, srcfile = NULL, keep.source = FALSE)
  
  # Apply `handler()` to each expression as text, then 
  # evaluate the expression as code
  for (expr in exprs) {
    handler(deparse(expr))
    eval(expr, envir)
  }
  
  # Return nothing
  invisible()
  
}
```

This will allow you to do anything you like with the code text before
it gets evaluated. E.g. you could apply some pretty HTML formatting and
then output it as a message, which would allow you to use something very similar to the code above, since `withCallingHandlers()` would handle
these messages for you:

```
# Define a function to show a message as code-formatted HTML
html_message <- function(msg) {
  with_linebreaks <- paste(msg, collapse = "<br/>")
  as_code <- sprintf("<code>%s</code>", with_linebreaks)
  spaces_preserved <- gsub(" ", "&nbsp", as_code)
  message(spaces_preserved)
}

# Then use very similar code to the above for `server`, so 
# something like -
tryCatch(
      withCallingHandlers(
        source2(file = paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials2.r"), 
                handler = html_message,
                local = TRUE),
        # ... Same code as in the above example using normal source()
```

### Bonus: Getting Fancy with HTML

If you want to get really fancy you could add some custom HTML formatting to each of your `message`/`warning`/`error` functions, e.g. you could show errors in red like so:

```
error = function(e) {
  shinyjs::html("modal_status", add = TRUE, sprintf(
    '<span style = "color: red;">%s</span><br/>', e$message
  ))
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking time to work on this! Unfortunately, it doesn't mirror R GUI messages but messages coded in R script(GUI_trials2.R). Like if execution of GUI_trials.R gives an error, that's not being captured, if I put in echo=TRUE in source statement, the messages which appear in R GUI(line-by line code) doesn't appear here. Is there a way to capture those?

Comment: Hm, I think I've misunderstood your question then. Could you please make an edit clarifying where `GUI_trials.r` is sourced/run? There's an obvious place where `GUI_trials2.r` is sourced but no references to the other script. However, the principles I've outlined above, i.e. using `tryCatch()` to handle errors and `withCallingHandlers()` to handle messages and warnings, should be enough to cover what you need, no?

Comment: Sorry, "GUI_trials.R" was a typo in above comment, please read it "GUI_trials2.R". I meant to ask if I change the source statement for "GUI_trials2.R" to include echo=T, is there any way to display those messages as well. Many thanks for tryCatch and other things, I was not aware of those and are very helpful, perhaps I can put in messages in sourced scripts to use this, but just wanted to check if there's another option here.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as that gives very nice workaround which I can use! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my solution to give something along the lines of `echo = TRUE` now :)

Comment: Thank you very very much! This is awesome! You're outstanding!